# Update end time and duration in same time, using TIMESTAMPDIFF PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, duration

I want to update '**duration**' and '**end_time**' field in same query/action. '**end_time**' field filled current time, '**duration**' field filled from different minute between '**start**' and '**end_time**' field. when i execute this update, the result in '**duration**' field is 0. How to get end_time and duration in same time.

this is the php code :

```
<?php
include("koneksi.php");
$id     = $_GET['id'];
$start  = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+60*60*7);
$end_time   = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+60*60*7);
$duration  = $_POST['duration'];


$query = "update billing set end_time='$end_time', duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '$start', '$end_time') where id='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result){
echo '<script language="javascript">window.location = "../?p=los"</script>'; 
} ?>
```

Comment: $id is coming from GET method and $duration is coming from POST method. A form cant be submitted using both method at a time.

Comment: please tell me the correct one, thanks

Comment: plz post your html code also

Comment: @rack_nilesh  echo "<a href='file/updatelos.php?id=$row[0]' title='click to stop'><font color=red>STOP</font></a> , thats code on my html, when i click that link it will return to updatelos.php , which code like post above.

Comment: You should not set the $start value here. Here $start and $end_time represent same value that is current time. That's why you get duration as 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duration is being set to 0 because `$start` and `$end_time` are the same.

Consider your code:

```
$start  = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+60*60*7);
$end_time   = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+60*60*7);

$query = "... TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '$start', '$end_time') ...";
```

Because `$start == $end_time`, the difference will always be 0.

You probably want to use the value of `start_time` already stored in the database, not the recently created php variable `$start`. Perhaps something like this:

```
$query = "
 update billing set 
 end_time='$end_time', 
 duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, '$end_time') 
 where id='$id'
";
```

where `start_time` is a column in the database.

---

*Note:*  [mysql_* functions are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), and you are susceptible to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Consider using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and utilize [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: if not  $start == $end_time, it will save nothing in  'duration' field when i execute. or you can help me to correct all my code above. thanks

Comment: @bangkosim In your table `billing` you have a field called `end_time`. You must also have a field called `start_time`, right? That is what you want to use in `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, ***not*** `$start`.

Comment: i already have that field and i named it with 'start'. in the code above I using $start to call that field from database. thanks

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer, and this is my fix code

```
$query = "update billing set , end_time='$end_time', 
 duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, '$end_time'),
 cost = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start, '$end_time') * (SELECT basiccost from costed where id ='1')
 where id='$id'";
```